# landing with east to west wind on runway 11/29

Tags: landing, runways, wind

i was wondering if anyone could help me out with this doubt i have. the kananga airport in dr congo has a single runway labelled 11/29. upon checking on google maps the number 11 is on the left end and the number 29 is on the right. if the wind is blowing east-west which of the two sides would i say i was landing on? i know planes land against the wind so i figured one would land from left to right , meaning one would land on runway 11. but after i read about runway numbering i got more confused because i understood that the number 11 should actually be on the right side rather than the left. can anyone help me understand why the runway  has an 11 on the left (which i understood should be west) and 29 on the right (supposedly east)? and if im correct to assume that with an east to west wind one should land from west to east meaning one would land on runway 11?? thanks a lot

Comment: The number for an eastward landing (11) is on the west end, since when you're landing towards the east, the west end of the runway is the first end you see.

Answer (score 2):

> if im correct to assume that with an east to west wind one should land from west to east meaning one would land on runway 11??

That is correct. The convention is that the runway number is the magnetic heading of the runway to the nearest 10 degrees, but with the low-order 0 removed. Thus, to the nearest 10 degrees, the magnetic heading of runway 11 is 110 degrees. That's the approximate heading the aircraft is going to have when they land on that runway. That would be a landing (or takeoff) to the east rather than the west. In other words, it's the heading of an aircraft using the runway as opposed to where the runway end is in a left-right sense when looking north.

Kolwezi Airport has only a 3° west magnetic variation. Thus, in your area magnetic heading and true heading are nearly the same.